# Jquery on php in div box not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have an main php that load a php into a div box via a dropdown list.
The loaded php contains a table. There is jquery in it that does an alert on row clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#newsTable tr').click(function(){
    var clickedId = $(this).children('td:first').text();
    alert(clickedId);
    });
});
```

But after it is loaded into the div, the script is not firing

Comment: is it loading inside just div or is script tag present as wrapper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use Event delegation to attach event. [Event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $(document).on('click','#newsTable tr',function(){
       var clickedId = $(this).children('td:first').text();
       alert(clickedId);
     });
   }); // End
```

Answer (score 1):

There is something with event delegation. Try using this code :

```
$('id_Or_Class_container_hold_the_php_data').on('click', 'tr', function(){
   var clickedId = $(this).children('td:first').text();
   alert(clickedId);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
(document).ready(function() {
```

with

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#newsTable tr').click(function(){
   var clickedId = $(this).children('td:first').text();
    alert(clickedId);
  });
});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use live query, instead of your click event u can use following.

$('#newsTable tr').on('click',function()

Answer (score 0):

Use below code..i think its working properly.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#newsTable").on('click','tr',function(){
       var clickedId = $(this).children('td:first').text();
       alert(clickedId);
     });
   });
```